# Does anyone know of an itextsharp migration guide from 4.x to 5.x?

Tags: .net, itext

I have just looked at using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) 5.0, however things like table/cell have been refactored. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a clear way to migrate from 4.x to the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is none, you simply have to bite the bullet and rewrite all uses.